# How many strings contain the letter A, allowing repetitions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The strings are of length $3$ composed of the letters ABCDE.

The answer is: $5^4 - 4^3$

I am not sure how to get this answer.

What is the difference between "How many strings begin with A, allowing repetitions" and the question above MATHEMATICALLY? I know the answers to both but I am not sure how to go about solving one vs. the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, there are $5^3$ possible strings of length $3$ using the given alphabet. Also, there are $4^3$ possible strings of length $3$ using the alphabet BCDE (all of which we have counted in our $5^3$ original strings). Therefore, $5^3-4^3$ strings remain, all of which must contain the letter A.

The questions are just counting different things. If you insist that the $3$ letter word starts with A, then you put A in the first position of the string and now there are two places remaining. How many ways are there to fill them?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach the problem is to count the number of strings with $1$, $2$, or $3$ A's:
$$\sum_{k=1}^3 \binom 3k 4^{3-k} = 3\cdot4^2+3\cdot4+1 = 48+12+1 = 61. $$